# using findAssocs to build a correlation matrix of all word combinations in R

Tags: r, text, correlation, tm

I'm trying to write code that builds a table that shows all the correlations between all the words from a corpus.

I know that I can use `findAssocs` in the `tm` package to find all word correlations for a single word i.e. `findAssocs(dtm, "quick", 0.5)` - would give me all the words that have a correlation with the word "quick" above 0.5, but I do not want to do this manually for each word in the text I have.

```
#Loading a .csv file into R
file_loc <- "C:/temp/TESTER.csv"
x <- read.csv(file_loc, header=FALSE)
require (tm)
corp <- Corpus(DataframeSource(x))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)

#Clean up the text
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(tolower))
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeNumbers)
corp <- tm_map(corp, removePunctuation)
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(stripWhitespace))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
```

From here I can find the word correlations for individual words:

```
findAssocs(dtm, "quick", 0.4)
```

But I want to find all the correlations like this:

```
       quick  easy   the   and 
quick   1.00  0.54  0.72  0.92     
 easy   0.54  1.00  0.98  0.54   
  the   0.72  0.98  1.00  0.05  
  and   0.92  0.54  0.05  1.00
```

Any suggestions?

Example of the "TESTER.csv" data file (starting from cell A1)

```
[1] I got my question answered very quickly
[2] It was quick and easy to find the information I needed
[3] My question was answered quickly by the people at stack overflow
[4] Because they're good at what they do
[5] They got it dealt with quickly and didn't mess around
[6] The information I needed was there all along
[7] They resolved it quite quickly
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: The actual data has around 1,000 of these comments

Answer (score 5):

You can probably use `as.matrix` and `cor`. `findAssocs` has a lower limit of 0:

```
(cor_1 <- findAssocs(dtm, colnames(dtm)[1:2], 0))
#               all along
#  there       1.00  1.00
#  information 0.65  0.65
#  needed      0.65  0.65
#  the         0.47  0.47
#  was         0.47  0.47
```

`cor` gets you all pearson correlations, for what it's worth:

```
cor_2 <- cor(as.matrix(dtm))
cor_2[c("there", "information", "needed", "the", "was"), c("all", "along")]
#                   all     along
# there       1.0000000 1.0000000
# information 0.6454972 0.6454972
# needed      0.6454972 0.6454972
# the         0.4714045 0.4714045
# was         0.4714045 0.4714045
```

The preceding code:

```
x <- readLines(n = 7)
[1] I got my question answered very quickly
[2] It was quick and easy to find the information I needed
[3] My question was answered quickly by the people at stack overflow
[4] Because they're good at what they do
[5] They got it dealt with quickly and didn't mess around
[6] The information I needed was there all along
[7] They resolved it quite quickly
library(tm)
corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(x))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(tolower))
corp <- tm_map(corp, removeNumbers)
corp <- tm_map(corp, removePunctuation)
corp <- tm_map(corp, content_transformer(stripWhitespace))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
```

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for the examples. I can get the second one using pearson correlations to work, but not your first example

Comment: I added the preceding code (and a round bracket, which I forgot)

Comment: Sorry Luke, but when I run that code I keep getting "numeric(0)"

Comment: I cannot reproduce it using tm_0.6 and R version 3.1.3.

Comment: I am using tm_0.6 and R version 2.15.3

Comment: @lukeA - nice answer.  Why do you sometimes use content_transformer and sometimes no in the clean-up code?

Comment: Sorry Luke. But even in R version 2.15.3 and 3.1.1 I can't reproduce your first result which is what I am looking for. I keep getting "numeric(0)" when I execute (cor1 <- findAssocs(dtm, colnames(dtm)[1:2], 0)) What am I missing?

Comment: @lawyeR to make sure `corp` stays a collection of `TextDocument`s, not `character` vectors. Otherwise `DocumentTermMatrix` would throw an error. It's not necessary for `tm::stripWhitespace` though.

Comment: @DrPaulVella I don't know. Here's my `sessionInfo()`: R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09), Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1, locale: LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252, LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C,  LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252, attached base packages: stats, graphics, grDevices, utils, datasets,  methods,   base, other attached packages: tm_0.6, NLP_0.1-6. Do you use NLP 0.1.6, too?

Comment: I have NLP 0.1.7 I noticed that the findAssocs and Pearson's are the same when positive so I can still get the result I need. The positive correlations indicate the two words are associated but could say that the strongly negative Pearson correlations indicate two words are not used together?

Comment: I suggest you to open a new question on how to interprete correlation coefficients using binary weighting or weighting by term frequency. May be sth for stats.stackexchange.com.